# Raw use of parameterized class 'MaterialDatePicker.Builder'

Tags: android, android-studio, builder, materialdatepicker

I am trying to implement a Date Picker but i am getting the following lint error

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'MaterialDatePicker.Builder'
```

Below is my code for the Material Date Picker

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

        builder.setTitleText("Select date range of publication");

        // If you want to set theme here
        //builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialTheme);

        MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(getParentFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");

        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> {

            etDatesToPublish.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());

        });
```

Comment: I have tried to answer your query. Please try running it thus and you mark it as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

The class expects a parameter which you have not provided to it and thus you are trying to use it raw.

It will be as follows

```java
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
```